# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}$ does not exists? How to prove?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}$ does not exists? How to prove? The terms involves both $i$ and $n$. How does Cauchy's criterion or others to apply?

Comment: This is a Riemann sum of $\int_0^1\frac{\sin x^{-1}}{x}dx$

Comment: @NinadMunshi: hi ,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{i}{n})=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$ I do not underatnd how $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}\to \int_0^1\frac{\sin x^{-1}}{x}dx$$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash. Multiply and divide by $n$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The improper integral, this result may not be right.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Is it converges to $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$? The improper integral...

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @xldd: Numerical calculations with Mathematica confirm your suggestion.

Comment: @xldd: Some of the commenters seem to be missing your point.  The integrand $\frac{1}{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded and is not Riemann integrable. As you say the integral is improper and since the integrand is not monotone the "Riemann sum" with evaluation at the right end-point of partition intervals may not converge to the value of the improper integral which is $0.624713...$  So your question of how to show non-convergence is appropriate.

Comment: A related question: [Convergence of sequences $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$ as $n\to\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141763)