# Convergence of sequences $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

My question is to prove the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$$
does not exist!

$\textbf{Background:}$
Generally, we have the following result:

> If $f$ is monotone on $(0,1]$, then
> $$\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx\ \mbox{exists} \iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\ \mbox{exists}.$$
> And in both case, we have
> $$\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$

If $f$ has no monotonicity, the above result may not be right.For example, let
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x},\ x\in(0,1].$$
It easy to see that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}dx
=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}du=0.624713\cdots.$$
But the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$$
doesn't seem to exist by numerical calculation using wolfram mathematica:For $n=1,2,\cdots,200$
[image]

Can someone provide a method to prove above limit does not exist.
Any help and hints will welcome!

Comment: Observe that in the use of the integral's definition we have $\;\cfrac1n\;$ , whereas in your sequence we have $\;\cfrac1k\;$ ...

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}.$$  @DonAntonio

Comment: Why is monotonicity important at all for riemann summation?

Comment: There is this older question - with no answers (and a few comments): [$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\sin\frac{n}{i}$ does not exists? How to prove?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3984670)

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak  Yes , you are right,I see that post.But I think there is no valuable comment in there.

Comment: Even if none of the questions has answers, it might be useful that they are linked to each other - is somebody finds one of them, they can look what was posted as a response to the other one. (Let's hope some useful answer will be added at least to one of them.) Unrelated to this question - some pointers on how to use comment replies can be found in the corresponding tag-info: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info (As you can easily guess, I wasn't pinged by the previous comment. Maybe that was intentional - I am definitely not complaining.)

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Riemann: This is a suggestion: focus on dyadic divisions of $(0,1]$, tat is $$R_n:=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum^{2^n}_{k=1}\frac{2^n}{k}\sin\Big(\frac{2^n}{k}\Big)$$
This is the integral of the step function
$$
S_n(x)=\sum^{2^n}_{k=1} f(2^{-n}k)\mathbb{1}_{(2^{-n}(k-1),2^{-n}k]}$$
where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\big(\frac1x\big)$. $S_{n+1}$ is obtained from $S_n$ by bisecting intervals and evaluation at middle points.

Answer (score 6):

Let $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$. To show that $a_n$ doesn't converge, it is enough to show that $a_{n+1}-a_n$ doesn't go to zero.

But $a_{n+1}-a_n=2\sin 0.5\cos \frac{2n+1}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^n2\frac{1}{k}\sin \frac{1}{2k}\cos \frac{2n+1}{2k}+ \frac{1}{n+1}\sin 1$

Now $2\sin 0.5=.988..$, while $|\sum_{k=2}^n2\frac{1}{k}\sin \frac{1}{2k}\cos \frac{2n+1}{2k}| \le \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} \le .65$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}\sin 1 \to 0$, so it is enough to find $n_m \to \infty$ st $\cos \frac{2n_m+1}{2}$ is close to $\pm 1$ for $|a_{n_m+1}-a_{n_m}| \ge .1$ say and by the uniform distribution of $\frac{2n+1}{2}$ modulo $2\pi$ we can definitely find such, so we are done!